# Django query where in

Tags: django, django-queryset

How to do this using django object query:

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE (test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM test_subject_set)) AND (test_begin_time < '') AND (test_end_time > '')
```

The model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)


class TestSubjectSet(models.Model):
    id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
```

Comment: please show your django model for this. And it wouldn't hurt to be more descriptive in what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Two querysets are [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in) way of doing this. It will be one database hit anyway.

```
test_ids = Subject.objects.all()
result = Test.objects.filter(test_id__in=test_ids).filter([some other filtering])
```

Answer (score 12):

DrTyrsa just about had it.

```
test_ids = list(TestSubjectSet.objects.all().values_list('test_id', flat=True))
result = Test.objects.filter(id__in=test_ids, test_begin_time__lt='', test_end_time__gt='')
```

The way Tyrsa was doing it would not give you a list of the Test ids from TestSubjectSet, but instead give you a TestSubjectSet queryset.

Also, I was confused by the test_begin_time and test_end_time fields, because you didn't mention them in your models.

Update: Used list() on the queryset, because, according to the link DrTyrsa posted, DBs "don't optimize nested querysets very well".

Comment: Thank you Bryce Siedschlaw. Does it make any different by using Values_list?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The values_list function will return the test_ids in every TestSubjectSet record. So, you'll end up with a list of integers related to the keys of Test records.

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw You are wrong. Querysets are lazy and `test_ids` will be evaluated only in the second line, producing absolutely the same SQL query. If you want to make two flat SQL queries (instead of one nested) you should write `id__in=list(test_ids)`, but both variatians get same `result`.

Comment: I guess I've never seen that method done before. It doesn't seem like it would work. I mean, you're filtering the id field on the Test model using the TestSubjectSet queryset. Does the filter function automagically know to look in all the TestSubjectSet records' test_id fields? If it does, then I've been doing things wrong for a long time now.

Comment: I must be missing something... I just tried your code on a test project and it came up with an error saying that the __in filter expects an integer not a model instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, didn't noticed it's `id`, not object. :-) There was no model code when I answered and I was sure it's a query filtered by some related object (`test_id` (before IN) looks exactly as foreign key).

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me:

```
Line.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2, 3])
```